# KineticJS: reduce sensitivity of drag event

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, touch, kineticjs

**The background:** I am trying to build an app where the user is able to perform an action by clicking two Kinetic shapes at the same time, but is also able to drag individual shapes around the canvas freely. I realise that KineticJS does not support multitouch (yet) but before addressing that issue I have encountered another problem.

**The problem:**
The touch screen I am using (a Planar 27" Helium, on Windows 8 in Chrome) seems to struggle to resolve touch events well. This means that 'clicking' (and holding down) a shape in Kinetic fires drag events and not the single click or tap event. I can visibly see the shape jumping around a few pixels underneath my finger while this is happening, which tells me that the touch event is moving location, even though the finger is staying in the same place.

**What I would like:**
A way to adjust the sensitivity of drag events, so that they only fire when the distance from the current shape location reaches a certain number of pixels. Ideally, the click event would fire, followed by dragstart after a certain threshold. I am assuming that stopping the drag event from firing initially will also mean that the shape will stop moving slightly under my finger as I hold down a press.

I have had a snoop around in the KineticJS source, but I can't seem to see where code like this should be implemented.

---

**SOLVED! Please see my solution below.**

Comment: What do you already have? Can you post a jsFiddle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue has been solved with the introduction of the `dragDistance` attribute in a recent commit in the KineticJS project (https://github.com/ericdrowell/KineticJS/commit/0b93e21e0b9e11165dfed7574dbafa0ae2a144e0, or see https://github.com/ericdrowell/KineticJS/pull/725 for the pull request)

To make use of the feature, simply assign the value (in pixels) that the drag must exceed before being triggered to the dragDistance attribute of a shape or group. `touchStart` events below this threshold will not trigger `dragStart`, meaning that the `tap` event is far more useful in touch scenarios now.

```
var rect = new Kinetic.Rect({
    draggable: true,
    dragDistance: 5
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically I think you have to bind click on target and do something only if happen something after a while:

```
/* #########################
   ########## HTML #########
   ######################### */

<div id='target'></div>

/* #########################
   ###### JAVASCRIPT #######
   ######################### */

var mousedownID = -1;  
var timer = 0;  /* tenth of second */      
var timeToDrag = 25;


var mousedown = function(event) {
  if(mousedownID==-1)  
     mousedownID = setInterval(whilemousedown, 100);
}

var mouseup = function(event) {
   if(mousedownID!=-1) {
     clearInterval(mousedownID);
     mousedownID=-1;
   }

}

var whilemousedown = function() {
  timer += 1;
  if( timer > timeToDrag ) {
     /* Call drag */
     /* if you want you can force mouseup calling mouseup() function */
  }
}

$('#target').mousedown(mousedown);
$('#targer').mouseup(mouseup);
```

You can take a look at the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JKfwe/). Hope this is helpfull!

## edit

Likewise, you can bind touchstart and touchend event:

```
$('#target').bind("touchstart", mousedown);
$('#target').bind("touchend", mouseup);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I think you have misunderstood. As I said in the question, I am using the KineticJS canvas library, which has its own events system. Also, I am dealing with touch, not mouse events.

Comment: @Velthune +1 You certainly have the right idea. KineticJS automatically handles binding so manually over-riding its eventing system requires non-standard code.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Kinetic's before* events to prevent dragging until a specific drag distance is reached.

However, the current version of KineticJS has removed all the `before*` events which would have been ideal for your situation.

You could look up a previous version and reinstall those before* events.

**Alternatively**

On touchstart you can tell the node to stop listening to events for a tiny period of time.

That way the node won't be listening for a short time and will not respond to your inadvertent finger twitches by starting a drag.

Here's `untested-probably-needs-tweeking-code` to shut down listening for a short time.

**Add properties on each node to define the delay:**

```
// delay 100ms when a delay is requested

myNode.delayAmount=100;

// initialize with no delay (delayUntil==0)

myNode.delayUntil=0;
```

**Add a touchstart handler that stops listening for this node until a time shortly in the future**

```
myNode.on("touchstart"){ 

    this.listening(false);

    this.delayUntil=new Date().now()+this.delayAmount;

    debounce(this);

}
```

**Periodically check if the delay time has elapsed.  If yes, turn listening back on**

```
function debounce(node){

    var delayUntil=node.delayUntil;

    if(delayUntil==0){return;}

    if((new Date().now())<delayUntil){
        requestAnimationFrame(debounce);
        return;
    }

    node.isListening(true);

    node.delayUntil=0;

    }

}
```